# TensorFlow 2 and Keras:

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When I want to use Keras with TensorFlow 2 I got this error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute
>   'get_default_graph'

Comment: Is your tensorflow updated to the latest version? Have you checked whether correct code file is getting called or not? Try this - try to run this code from spyder IDE. Once you reach this error, check whether the correct version of ops.py file is getting called or not.

Answer (score 2):

The Keras API (https://keras.io/) has multiple implementations, including the original and reference implementation (https://github.com/keras-team/keras), but also various other implementations, including tf.keras, which is part of TensorFlow.

So there are two ways you can use Keras with TensorFlow:

1. Using the reference implementation with the TensorFlow backend. However, this implementation has not been updated to support TensorFlow 2 yet (as of June 2019).
2. Using TensorFlow's implementation, tf.keras. This one works fine with TF 2.

To use tf.keras, you must make sure to use the correct imports:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
# NOT: import keras
```

Similarly, use:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
# Not from keras.layers import Dense
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since TensorFlow 2 defaults to eager execution Keras will need some changes in order to be compatible with it, but until then a previous version of TensorFlow is required.